# Preencher um campo text com as informações de outro campo ao clicar em um radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como eu faria para que o texto digitado no campo abaixo:

```
<label for="nomeUsuario">Coordenador:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeUsuario" id="nomeUsuario">
```

Ao clicar no radio button:

```
<label>Selecione o coordenador:</label>
<input type="radio" name="Coordenador" value="">
```

Aparecesse automaticamente o nome do usuário digitado anteriormente no campo abaixo?

```
<label for="nomeCoordenador">Coordenador:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeCoordenador" id="nomeCoordenador">
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara qui tem um exemplo bem simples, basta vc pegar o value de um campo e botar no outro com o click no rádio. Vc tem que fazer um eventLiestener no check, que quando for clicado executa a função que vai pegar o value de um campo e mudar o value do outro.

Basicamente é isso no click do radio

```
var eu = nomeUsuario.value;
nomeCoordenador.value = eu;
```

Para entender melhor veja abaixo o exemplo funcionando

```js
let nomeUsuario = document.getElementById('nomeUsuario');
let Coordenador = document.querySelector('[name="Coordenador"]');
let nomeCoordenador = document.getElementById('nomeCoordenador');

function mostra() {
    var eu = nomeUsuario.value;
    nomeCoordenador.value = eu;
}

Coordenador.addEventListener('click', mostra);
```

```html
<label for="nomeUsuario">Coordenador:</label><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeUsuario" id="nomeUsuario"><br>
Ao clicar no radio button:<br>

<label>Selecione o coordenador:</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="Coordenador" value=""><br>
Aparecesse automaticamente o nome do usuário digitado anteriormente no campo abaixo:<br>

<label for="nomeCoordenador">Coordenador:</label><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeCoordenador" id="nomeCoordenador"><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma simples com jQuery, que só checa o radiobutton e adiciona o nome no outro campo se o primeiro campo tiver alguma *coisa* digitada:

```js
$("[name=Coordenador]").on("click", function(){
   var nu = $("#nomeUsuario").val().trim();
   nu ? $("#nomeCoordenador").val(nu) : this.checked = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="nomeUsuario">Coordenador:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeUsuario" id="nomeUsuario">
<br><br>
<label>Selecione o coordenador:</label>
<input type="radio" name="Coordenador" value="">
<br><br>
<label for="nomeCoordenador">Coordenador:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeCoordenador" id="nomeCoordenador">
```

Uma versão em JavaScript puro para a mesma coisa:

```js
document.querySelector("[name=Coordenador]").onclick = function(){
   var nu = document.getElementById("nomeUsuario").value.trim();
   nu ? document.getElementById("nomeCoordenador").value = nu : this.checked = false;
}
```

```html
<label for="nomeUsuario">Coordenador:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeUsuario" id="nomeUsuario">
<br><br>
<label>Selecione o coordenador:</label>
<input type="radio" name="Coordenador" value="">
<br><br>
<label for="nomeCoordenador">Coordenador:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeCoordenador" id="nomeCoordenador">
```

> O `.trim()` é para remover possíveis espaços em branco digitados no
>   início e/ou final do input. Caso considere isso desnecessário, é só
>   remover o `.trim()` do código.

Answer (score 1):

É bem simples de uma olhada no código em baixo.

```js
function selecioneCoordenador()
{
    var nomeUsuario = window.document.querySelector("#nomeUsuario");
    var selecionar = window.document.querySelector("#selecionar");
    var nomeCoordenador = window.document.querySelector("#nomeCoordenador");

    selecionar.addEventListener("input", function ()
    {
        nomeCoordenador.value = nomeUsuario.value;
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", selecioneCoordenador);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <label for="nomeUsuario">Coordenador:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeUsuario" id="nomeUsuario">
    <br/>
    <label>Selecione o coordenador:</label>
    <input id="selecionar" type="radio" name="Coordenador" value="">

    <label for="nomeCoordenador">Coordenador:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NomeCoordenador" id="nomeCoordenador">

</body>
</html>
```

No seu *HTML* eu apenas coloquei um `id="selecionar"`. Já no *JavaScript* criei uma função `selecioneCoordenador()` que sera chamada quando a página for carregada, dentro dessa função declarei 3 variáveis com valores fazendo referêcia aos `id` no *HTML*, depois só adicionei um evento `input` no `selecionar` que é o `input="radio"` e quando esse evento ocorrer o valor de `nomeCoordenador` que é o `input="text"` com `id="nomeCoordenador"` vai receber o valor de `nomeUsuario` que é o `input="text"` com `id="nomeUsuario"`.